# Is this possible to develop the API Script using Test Server ReadyAPI License

Tags: ready-api

I am working in `ReadyAPI` Project.

I have an ReadyAPI's `Testserver` where the license is installed.

I can able to execute the existing API scripts using Test server with help of the tool "cURL".

Is this possible to develop the scripts using **ReadyAPI *TestServer***? If Yes, Where i need to import the Test Server IP details in my ReadyAPI?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are in confused state based on the question.

**ReadyAPI** has suite of tools to test the functionality / load / mock functionality of API.

**SoapUI NG** is the one of the product from the above suite which you need to use design your tests (in the from of project > test suite > test case > test steps). In case, need to know how create project, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Bzg5dALQqM) helps.

Where as **TestServer** is concerted, it is just used to execute the tests; but not for creating scripts.

Here is excerpt from [documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testserver/index.html):

> ReadyAPI TestServer is a GUI-less application that runs on your local computer or on some other machine in your network and executes API tests. The topics of this section contain detailed information on using TestServer.

Hope the above clarifies your queries.

The above document link helps you to get started with test server as well.